# How to move a table from SAS to Teradata SQL Assistant?

Tags: sas, teradata

I would like to ask you how to move a table from SAS to TeradataSQL Assistant.

What I have done in SAS is to define a libname, then create the table that I want to move in Teradata.

```
libname NAME "/path"

proc sql;
create table WORK.EXAMPLE as(
select *
from DATASET
);
quit;
```

However, I do not know if I need to connect SAS to Teradata in this way:

```
libname NAME teradata USER=tduser PASSWORD=tdpasswd SERVER=TDServ ; 

proc sql;
   connect to teradata (
tdpid=“” user=“” password=“”);
create table WORK.EXAMPLE as 
select * from connection to teradata
(select * from DATASET
); quit;
```

My questions are:

1. in the second libname, where should I consider the path?
2. which one of the code above should I consider and why?
3. how can I 'call' this table in Teradata? I tried with `SELECT * FROM WORK.EXAMPLE`, but it does not exist.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: WORK is a temp table and remain accessible only during execution. To persist the dataset, you would need to reference NAME (what you named your lib) rather than WORK in your CREATE statement in the first section. Then, in your second area, you could then reference that table within your lib without having to create additional temp tables.

Comment: Thanks Kade. If I understood well what you said, I need to write `proc sql;
create table NAME.EXAMPLE as(
select *
from DATASET
);
quit;` . But how could I move the table to Teradata? I tried to write `select * from NAME.EXAMPLE` but even in this case the table does not exist. Do I need to use `connect to Teradata` in SAS?

Comment: After running the first: `PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE LIBNAME.TBL_NAME AS SELECT * FROM DATASET; QUIT;` you should be able to simply do 'PROC SQL; SELECT * FROM LIBNAME.TBL_NAME; QUIT` as your lib should be accessible from within your SAS Workspace... however, this is very dependent upon how your environment is set up.

Comment: So this means that the table is already uploaded in Teradata. But how I connect SAS to Teradata if I do not use connect to? It is a stupid question, but these concepts are new to me

Comment: The SQL assistant tool from Teradata is just a utility for accessing your Teradata database so it doesn't really have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I asked for my understanding as it is not clear how it works. I thought that I had to use `proc sql;
   connect to teradata ...` in the code to connect to Teradata. Would it be also required   `libname NAME teradata USER=tduser PASSWORD=tdpasswd SERVER=TDServ ; ` or the first example, `libname NAME "/path"`,  would be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either connect to Terdata using the LIBNAME statement

```
libname mylib TERADATA .... ;
```

or the CONNECT statement in PROC SQL.

```
proc sql;
  connect to teradata .... ;
```

In fact you can even use the libref created in a previously created LIBNAME statement in your connect statement.

```
libname mylib TERADATA .... ;
proc sql;
  connect using mylib ;
```

Generally I find it easiest to use PROC APPEND to copy data into Teradata.

```
libname td TERADATA ... ;
libname mysas 'path to where my SAS datasets live';
proc append base=td.target_table data=mysas.source_table force;
run;
```

If the target table doesn't exist then SAS will create it. (In which case take care as you might not want the default variable types or the primary index that will get created that way.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tom. Then, when I create a libname mylib TERADATA, this should be what I need to add once I call my table in Teradata: `select * from mylib.table`, should not?

Comment: Yes.  Note that in the libname you will connect to a specific database on the teradata server.  So the name TABLE will be the name of the table in that database.   The name you use for your libref in SAS is limited to 8 characters, but the name of your database in Teradata could be longer than that.  So when running code directly in Teradata (via SQL Assistant or using passthru code from SAS) you should use the database name (somedb.table) and not the SAS libref (mylib.table) you invented to use in the libname statement.

Comment: is there any way to know that database I am using? I have no information on that ini my exercise

Comment: You probably have a default database assigned for your account. So inside Teradata you can just use a one level name for the tables. When using the SAS libref just prefix that to the one level name.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but a couple SQL requests you can run in SQL Assistant to get more info: `HELP DATABASE <db_name>;` will give you the list of objects (tables, views, macros...) within a given database; `SELECT DATABASE;` will give you your current default database for that session.  So if you run `SELECT * FROM MyTable` it will qualify `MyTable` with your default database.